# Add background to an Android VectorDrawable

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable, android-icons

For the background of my logo my designer gave me an svg file. I added the background in an adaptive icon drawable but unfortunately, the AndroidStudio tool that creates my vector drawable `ic_background` ignores the white background of the svg file that got set in document preferences.

What's the best way to add my white background?

```
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_background"  />
    <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_foreground" />
</adaptive-icon>
```

Comment: try to use src:svgfile and background:white, for an imageView

Answer (score 0):

Add a white background while you are importing that Vector Drawable to the Android Studio.